# Search in the app with fragments

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, search, android-adapter

I'm Trying to implement a search using a listview as a fragment.
In the MainActivity I use toolbar.
Fragment with a listview:

```
public class ListViewFragment extends Fragment {

ArrayList<Contact> contacts;
private ContactAdapter contactAdapter;
private DbWorker db;
private ListView listView;
private String orderBy;

private SearchView.OnQueryTextListener queryTextListener;
private SearchView searchView;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity class";
private static final String SORT_BY = "sortBy" ;
private final static String SORT_BY_NAME = "name";
private final static String SORT_BY_CATEGORY = "category";

public ListViewFragment(){}

public static ListViewFragment newInstanceLvFragment(final String typeOfSort) {
    final ListViewFragment listViewFragment = new ListViewFragment();

    final Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
    args.putString(SORT_BY, typeOfSort);

    listViewFragment.setArguments(args);
    return listViewFragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    final Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    if (arguments == null || !arguments.containsKey(SORT_BY)) {
        orderBy = null;
    } else {
        orderBy = arguments.getString(SORT_BY);
    }
}

@Override   
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewfragment, container, false);

    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

    new DbAsyncTask(v.getContext()).execute();

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {...}
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) v.findViewById(R.id.fabAdd);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {...}
    });
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    queryTextListener = new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            contactAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
    };

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(queryTextListener);
    searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   //Here is the sorting code. Works without problems}

private class DbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<Contact>> {
    private Context ctx;

    public DbAsyncTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Contact> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            db = new DbWorker(ctx);
            contacts = (ArrayList<Contact>) db.selectAllContacts(orderBy);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception in AsyncTask.doInBackground");
        }
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
        contactAdapter = new ContactAdapter(ctx, contacts);

        listView.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
    }
}
```

The adapter code:

```
public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater lInflater;
private ArrayList<Contact> contactList;
private ArrayList<Contact> filteredContactList;
private ContactFilter contactFilter;

public ContactAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Contact> contacts) {
    this.ctx = context;
    this.contactList = contacts;
    this.filteredContactList = contacts;
    this.lInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    getFilter();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return contactList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public Contact getContact(int position) {
    return ((Contact) getItem(position));
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.main, parent, false);
    }

    final Contact c = getContact(position);

    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactName)).setText(c.getContactName());
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactPhone)).setText(c.getContactPhone());
    TextView contactCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactCategory);
    contactCategory.setText(c.getContactCategory());
    TextView contactOrg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactOrg);
    contactOrg.setText(c.getContactOrgName());

    if (c.getContactCategory().equalsIgnoreCase("Private")) {
        contactOrg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    Button buttonCall = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonCall);
    buttonCall.setFocusable(false);
    buttonCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {...}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (contactFilter == null) {
        contactFilter = new ContactFilter();
    }
    return contactFilter;
}

private class ContactFilter extends Filter {

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint !=null  && constraint.length() > 0) {
            ArrayList<Contact> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Contact contact : contactList) {
                if (contact.getContactName().toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    tempList.add(contact);
                }
            }
            filterResults.count = tempList.size();
            filterResults.values = tempList;
        } else {
            filterResults.count = contactList.size();
            filterResults.values = contactList;
        }
        return filterResults;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        filteredContactList = (ArrayList<Contact>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

In the end search does not work. I enter data in search field, but nothing happens.
What's wrong with my code? Help to understand, please.

Comment: In the adapter, try replaced "contactList" with "filteredContactList" in the methods getCount() and getItem(int position). Hope that help!

Comment: @ I_A_Mok Unfortunately, it didn't help.
I added logging and saw that getFilter() is not invoked. I think the problem is that the toolbar is in MainActivity.
The fragment does not see the toolbar. Need to find a toolbar in a fragment.

Comment: @I_A_Mok Sorry, friend, it works! At first, I did wrong, but then I reread the message and changed it

Comment: As I understand "contactLis"t and the "filteredContactList" was confused between them.